# Target an ad using Facebook page ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I have a question regarding the ads-api.
I'm trying to find a way to target an ad to an audience that liked specific page(s).
The only way I see is to work with keywords for precise interests which is not a very good practice due to duplicates and pages that are not indexed.
Is there a way to pass an array of page ids as parameter for precise ad targeting?
Could not find it anywhere and it looks kind of trivial.
I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to target fans of a specific page or application unless you are an admin of that page.

The only option is to use interest targeting which will allow you to target people by interests but this does not necessarily mean they like a page.